# SocketExpection: connection failed (os Error permission denied , errno=13), adress=encrypted-tbn0.gastatic.com,port=443 in flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

This was error appears when i run my app in physical android device. i also added permession in AndroidManifest.xml
[image]
This is basically image Which uses image.network
And that url was decoded from Json something weird appears on terminal well weird atleast for me which is this :
[image]
why my app want to connect with more over it works in emulator and chrome but not in physical device
i tried after restarting laptop VS code wifi wifi router but nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the app if you are on physical device if on emulator go to avd managar and clear the memory it worked for me